# mysql_fetch_array showing the first row only when using while loop

Tags: php

shortly I'm facing an issue using while loop... I don't know what is going on, So, I thought that I should ask for help, after a lot of searches, I know that **mysql_fetch_array** returns a **row** in every time, so we should use **while** if we need to get all rows from the query.
and after trying to avoid **while** and use **foreach** I found that simply we can't use **foreach** instead of **while** or we can use it as another loop after **while**.
anyways, my problem is: I created a stored procedure in [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) database, and it working fine throw my [php](/questions/tagged/php) code using [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), but when I tried to put it in a loop based on IDs of some data, the **while loop** gave me the first row only after calculations.
so please if anyone can see what I can't see in the code, don't hesitate.
thanks..

```
$startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
$enddate = $_POST['enddate'];
$thefinalres="";    
$loop = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mrh_chains order by id");
        if ($loop){
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($loop))
            {
                $theid = $row['id'];
                $thename = $row['name'];
                //CALL PROCEDURE 
                $result = mysql_query("CALL calccommission($theid,'$startdate','$enddate')");
                if ($result){
                    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    if ($row2[0]!=""){
                        $thecommission = $row2[0];
                    } else {
                        $thecommission = "Try to change dates, There are no data on these dates";
                    }
                    $thefinalres .= $thename . " commission: ". $thecommission . "<br/>";
                }
            }

            $value =  array('msg' => 'true' );
            $value["res"] = $thefinalres;

        } else {
            $value =  array('msg' => 'false' );
        }
```

Comment: So are you sure `SELECT * FROM mrh_chains order by id` returns multiple rows? And are you sure the issue is iteration and not conditional logic? Add some debug lines?

Comment: yeah sure, even when I tried the **while loop** a lone in a [tag:php] file, it worked fine, and got all rows, but here after the procedure, it gives me the first row only

Comment: Did you checked log files for errors ?

Comment: checked, no errors at all

Comment: You aren't checking for errors. And having a query inside a loop isn't a good approach.

Comment: I'm checking for error if the first query has no rows, but the second query, I'm sure it will retrieve data (row of calculation result) so it will be an extra line of code if I checked for it.. beside, is there a problem to do a query inside a loop?!

Comment: Echo something before the `if ($result)...`

Comment: **echo "test echo ";** in response tab (of dev tools in chrome) I got 500 'test echo'

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Check the value of `$result`.  Can't see the SQL behind the procedure call. Nothing jumps out, think you need to debug your code. You aren't stomping on the `$result` variable. Would think the change to `order by id` is a red herring, has nothing to do with it, or how did it change the equation?

Comment: @Hossam; Can you please explain, what do you mean by after the procedure? Were you using plain query first and later you used store procedure? I am pretty sure, its something in code to call the procedure or  something is in procedure.

Comment: @Sam , I mean that I did a **while loop** after a simple query **mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mrh_chains order by id")** and it worked great, but when I did a **while loop** after query **mysql_query("CALL calccommission($theid,'$startdate','$enddate')")** it gives me the 1st row only. and I did called a **stored procedure** after a plain query to get IDs that I'll pass to the procedure.. beside I'm sure that the procedure working more than fine.. and after I did the solution "which I post it as an answer" every thing worked great, but still I don't know what is going on with the 1st code above!

Answer (score 0):

after a looooooooooooooooot of search, I found solution with [mysqli](/questions/tagged/mysqli)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(  "HOST", "USR", "PWD", "DBNAME" );
$ivalue=1;
$res = $mysqli->multi_query( "CALL myproc($ivalue,@x);SELECT @x" );
if( $res ) {
  $results = 0;
  do {
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
      printf( "<b>Result #%u</b>:<br/>", ++$results );
      while( $row = $result->fetch_row() ) {
        foreach( $row as $cell ) echo $cell, "&nbsp;";
      }
      $result->close();
      if( $mysqli->more_results() ) echo "<br/>";
    }
  } while( $mysqli->next_result() );
}
$mysqli->close();
```

I found answer in this article: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,198596,198717